# Correct way to get " " to print

Tags: php

Starting over Since I am terrible at question asking..haha

I am using a .php script that displays information to the user.

```
echo CHtml::tag("hr");
echo "<b>Crontab Command Line</b>:";
echo CHtml::opentag("pre");
echo "(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo '@reboot sleep 60 && {$coin->program} -
daemon -txindex -shrinkdebugfile') | crontab -\n";
echo "\n";
echo CHtml::closetag("pre");
```

when it displays on the webpage it shows as

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "@reboot sleep 60 && ${coin->program} -daemon 
-txindex -shrinkdebugfile") | crontab -\n
```

I am trying to correctly have it display

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "@reboot sleep 60 && variablename -daemon 
-txindex -shrinkdebugfile") | crontab -\n
```

So that the user can copy and paste that line in to SSH and have it added to the users cron

its displayed to be copied to the CLI

Comment: I think you used the wrong tag

Comment: Please clarify your question, which programming language are you using?

Comment: sorry not sure why the tag didnt hold but its php

Answer (score 0):

Change the inner double quotes to single quotes. You're not using any bash variables inside the string, so there's no need to use double quotes in the bash command.

```
echo "(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo '@reboot sleep 60 && {$coin->program} -daemon -txindex -shrinkdebugfile') | crontab -\n";
```

[Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

If you really do need double quotes in the `bash` command you're writing, you can escape them.

```
echo "(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo \"@reboot sleep 60 && {$coin->program} -daemon -txindex -shrinkdebugfile\") | crontab -\n";
```

Comment: Thank you! that printed the " " but now it doesnt print from {$coin->program}

Comment: What do you expect that to print?

Comment: `bash` doesn't use `->` after variables. Are you sure this isn't PHP?

Comment: hmmm i had selected php not sure why it switched to the other two

Comment: The question originally was tagged `c++`.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add back the `;` when I switched from bash to php.

Comment: we are back to the single ' when it needs to be a double. Sorry for all the bother

Comment: Why do you think the inner quotes need to be double quotes rather than single quotes?

Comment: ive update the question to hopefully explain better of what i am after

Comment: `$` should be after `{` not before it.

Comment: `${coin->program}` should be `{$coin->program}`